# Powershell IIS works in command line but not in asp.net

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a `add-website` script via asp.net. Where I want to be able to easily add new websites as an administrator. But I have the issue the command is not recognized.

The command line output:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>powershell new-website

cmdlet New-Website at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name:
```

The asp.net output:

```
The term 'new-website' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

My code is simple and to the point:

```
    Dim runspace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace
    ' open it
    runspace.Open()
    Dim pipeline As Pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript("new-website")
    ' add an extra command to transform the script
    ' output objects into nicely formatted strings
    ' remove this line to get the actual objects
    ' that the script returns. For example, the script
    ' "Get-Process" returns a collection
    ' of System.Diagnostics.Process instances.

    Dim results As Collection(Of PSObject) = pipeline.Invoke
    ' close the runspace
    runspace.Close()
    Dim stringBuilder As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
    For Each obj As PSObject In results
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString)
    Next
    Throw New Exception(stringBuilder.ToString)
```

Anyone has any clue why I can access it through the command line, but not the asp.net powershell?

Answer (score 1):

If I open PowerShell, the commandlet `New-Website` is not available. I need to

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
```

first, so I suspect you need to do that in your code somehow. Do you have modules configured to autoload for your shell?

Comment: Already tried that to add that command, but then it has the same error, but with the `import-module webadministration` in the sport of `new-website`

Comment: @Niels well, that's a pretty big tip-off to what the problem is.  Can you call ***any*** cmdlets from your asp.net code?

Comment: I can call `get-service` for example. Also I can do `invoke-command` which works if I call a PS1 file. But I like to know why I can't call it directly from the asp.net powershell.